# How to make CSS transitions and animations work together in this CSS Slider?

Tags: css, animation, slider, carousel, transition

https://jsfiddle.net/2btt0qdp/

This CSS Slider works well when you click on each input button.

It also works automatically, and loops accordingly.

But they do not work well together. When I click on any input button, the automatic animation still kicks in and loops, and slides an image that doesn't exist. Try it and see. I just can't seem to make it work.

How do I make the CSS transitions and animations work together, to make this CSS Slider function as it should?

```
<div id="slideshow-wrap">
<input type="radio" id="button-1" name="controls" checked="checked"/>
<label for="button-1"></label>
<input type="radio" id="button-2" name="controls"/>
<label for="button-2"></label>
<input type="radio" id="button-3" name="controls"/>
<label for="button-3"></label>
<input type="radio" id="button-4" name="controls"/>
<label for="button-4"></label>
<input type="radio" id="button-5" name="controls"/>
<label for="button-5"></label>
<label for="button-1" class="arrows" id="arrow-1">></label>
<label for="button-2" class="arrows" id="arrow-2">></label>
<label for="button-3" class="arrows" id="arrow-3">></label>
<label for="button-4" class="arrows" id="arrow-4">></label>
<label for="button-5" class="arrows" id="arrow-5">></label>
<div id="slideshow-inner">
    <ul>
        <li id="slide1">
            <img src="" style="background-color: orange; width: 100%;" />
        </li>
        <li id="slide2">
            <img src="" style="background-color: red; width: 100%;" />
        </li>
        <li id="slide3">
            <img src="" style="background-color: yellow; width: 100%;" />
        </li>
        <li id="slide4">
            <img src="" style="background-color: green; width: 100%;" />
        </li>
        <li id="slide5">
            <img src="" style="background-color: blue; width: 100%;" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1 { color: white }

#slideshow-wrap {
    display: block;
    height: 320px;
    margin: auto;   
    position: relative;
}

#slideshow-inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#slideshow-inner>ul {
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 500%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    -moz-transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    -o-transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    -webkit-animation:slide 16s infinite;
    -moz-animation: slide 16s infinite;
      -o-animation: slide 16s infinite;
    animation: slide 16s infinite;
}

#slideshow-inner>ul>li {
    width: 20%;
    height: 320px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#slideshow-inner>ul>li>img {
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio] {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 15px;
    z-index: 100;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#slideshow-wrap label:not(.arrows):not(.show-description-label) {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -15px;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background-color: silver;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#slideshow-wrap label:not(.arrows):active { bottom: -15px }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-1:checked~label[for=button-1] { background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1) }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~label[for=button-2] { background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1) }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~label[for=button-3] { background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1) }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~label[for=button-4] { background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1) }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~label[for=button-5] { background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1) }

#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-1] { margin-left: -36px }

#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-2] { margin-left: -18px }

#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-4] { margin-left: 18px }

#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-5] { margin-left: 36px }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-1:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul { left: 0 }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul { left: -100% }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul { left: -200% }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul { left: -300% }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul { left: -400% }

label.arrows {
    font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
    font-size: 25px;
    color: rgb(255,255,240);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}

label.arrows:hover { opacity: 1 }

label.arrows:active { margin-top: -23px }

input[type=radio]#button-1:checked~.arrows#arrow-2, input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~.arrows#arrow-3, input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~.arrows#arrow-4, input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~.arrows#arrow-5 {
    right: -55px;
    display: block;
}

input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~.arrows#arrow-1, input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~.arrows#arrow-2, input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~.arrows#arrow-3, input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~.arrows#arrow-4 {
    left: -55px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}

input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~.arrows#arrow-1 { left: -19px }

input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~.arrows#arrow-2 { left: -37px }

input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~.arrows#arrow-4 { left: -73px }

@-webkit-keyframes slide{
    0%,100% {
        margin-left:0%;
    }

    10% {
        margin-left:0%;
    }

    20% {
        margin-left:-100%;
    }

    30% {
        margin-left:-100%;
    }

    40% {
        margin-left:-200%;
    }

    50% {
        margin-left:-200%;
    }

    60% {
        margin-left:-300%;
    }

    70% {
        margin-left:-300%;  
    }
    80% {
        margin-left:-400%;  
    }
    90% {
        margin-left:-400%;  
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes slide{
    0%,100% {
        margin-left:0%;
    }

    10% {
        margin-left:0%;
    }

    20% {
        margin-left:-100%;
    }

    30% {
        margin-left:-100%;
    }

    40% {
        margin-left:-200%;
    }

    50% {
        margin-left:-200%;
    }

    60% {
        margin-left:-300%;
    }

    70% {
        margin-left:-300%;  
    }
    80% {
        margin-left:-400%;  
    }
    90% {
        margin-left:-400%;  
    }
}
@keyframes slide{
    0%,100% {
        margin-left:0%;
    }

    10% {
        margin-left:0%;
    }

    20% {
        margin-left:-100%;
    }

    30% {
        margin-left:-100%;
    }

    40% {
        margin-left:-200%;
    }

    50% {
        margin-left:-200%;
    }

    60% {
        margin-left:-300%;
    }

    70% {
        margin-left:-300%;  
    }
    80% {
        margin-left:-400%;  
    }
    90% {
        margin-left:-400%;  
    }
}
```

Comment: So do you want to pause the animation when the input is clicked?

Comment: Yes, something like that, as long as it works as intended. But it needs to resume looping too, not just pause indefinitely.

Comment: Well do you want a CSS only solution? Because you could manipulate animation-play-state is JS

Comment: Yes CSS. I intended to make this using only CSS, or I could have achieved this easier with Javascript.

Comment: OK, I see.  Well how about manipulating each individual slide rather than the whole slideshow when you click the inputs?

Comment: Better yet, use transformations rather than position / left so that you can manipulate all of the offsets absolutely and not relatively.